# Something that escapes me about Symfony's controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony

Take a look to that code

```
<?php

namespace Sestante\SestanteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sestante\SestanteBundle\Model\StrutturaManager;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('SestanteSestanteBundle:Main:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function showLodgingsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SestanteSestanteBundle:Struttura');
        $usr = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $usrId = $usr->getId();
        $sm = new StrutturaManager($repo);
        $lodgingList = $sm->retrieveLodgingsFromUser($usrId);
        return $this->render('SestanteSestanteBundle:Main:showLodgings.html.twig',array('lodgingList' => $lodgingList));
    }
}
```

This is a controller for an application that I've been writing.

Take a look to `showLodgingsAction`. I've tryied to place all business logic into a model (`StrutturaManager`) that with a repository (that I've passed directly from controller because, as far I know, they're available only here or via D.I.) query my db, do some elaboration and return a list that I'll render onto a template.

First question: Is this "code separation" good, or exists a better way for do what I'm trying to do?

Second question: suppose that, now, I want to use an object of `StrutturaManager` type into `indexAction`. Remember that mine object want a repository. So, have I to declare again, and again, and again, all my object for every controller's action where I want to use them? I suppose that must exist a smarter method but, at the moment, I don't understand which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `StrutturaManager` as a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and inject the `EntityManager` into it. This way the manager will have access to repositories you need and controllers won't know about Doctrine nor repositories — which is a good practice.

Comment: Ok, and this is what was my first idea. Theres a "but", however. Let's say that I've followed your suggest. I've got mine service and so on. Have I to recall it in every action with `$this->get('struttura_manager')` (let's say that struttura_manager is the registered name of this service)?

Comment: Yes. Or you could [define your controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and inject the manager and other services via constructor and then use them like `$this->strutturaManager`.

Comment: It makes sense to me, but what worries me is another - the last point, I promise :P - is that I have, let's say, ten entities and for every entity have I to make a service like xxxxManager, yyyyManager and so on ?

Comment: Yea, it's *almost* always `1:1` between models and their managers.