# Symfony2: Is better to use session object or my own manager?

Tags: symfony, twig

Related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479187/something-that-escapes-me-about-symfonys-controllers) question.
I've understood that I have to create some services for handle my entity and so on. That's because I have to "move" my logic away from controllers and place into "managers" (i.e. services)

Now I have a service that have some logic into it. In that service I, depending on user, return a list of "associated object" - say that those object are sport's team.
Let's say that first element of my list (generated from a repository somehow) is the "default" team and say that I have a page were I can change it **FOR all session long**. 
After log out or sessions stale, I want to return at "default" situation.

So my idea was: "since I've wrote a manager for this entity, I'll write a private attribute in this class where load (from db) this property and store (temporarily, with setter method) my changes."
This doesn't affect my db and I can keep my information for all session long.

But a thought came into my mind: how about session object? (is a service, if I didn't understood wrong)
Is my solution a good solution, or is better to store my information into session object?
From my point of view it's the same except that I can read session's variables directly from twig by using `app.session`. Am I wrong?

Moreover, if I'm not wrong, how can I access my object properties from twig without each time pass them from controller? (is much like having a global variable that I want to display everywhere into my application pages).

**Edit:**

More information can be found in [this chat transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5425143#5425143).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a variable for the duration of a session (for example, login until logout or as long as the user doesn't close his browser window) you have to store it in the session object. If you want to store a variable for the duration of a request, you can store it in the manager service.

However, you can use the manager service to load the session variable and make it available to the controller.

Just like it is a good idea to decouple the controller from the database/Doctrine it is also a good idea to decouple the controller from the session.

Update: As mentioned in the comments when looking at REST it is not a good idea to do the session stuff in the service. However, you should still store the variables in the session and use the controller to set the value in the service.

Comment: Yuo dind't understood my question. I don't want to store data temporarily into an entity, neither to persist it to db. I have my entity and read/write from/to it with ORM and entity manager. I don't want to change this. My questions is about what I call "managers". I've create a class and declare it as a service (as elnur hint me in previous question). Now that I have that service that is place between controller and repository, is a good practice to use it for store some variables,or is better to do that into session? This is the question

Comment: Actually, it's *not* a good idea to decouple controllers from sessions — that's exactly where the work with sessions belong. On the contrary, managers should *not* know about sessions at all, because sessions make sense only for some types of users — say, Web users — while they don't make sense, say, for a REST API — but both will use the same managers.

Comment: @elnur: if I use a manager only for this purpose, and if I have always to keep those information, this doesn't changes your answer? Moreover, as far I know services had a "state". Isn't it? Because if I call a setXXX on my service, into a controller, when i call the getXXX into another controller, it seem that my previous value assign isn't conserved

Comment: I think i understand how you want to use your service. But a service is just a function whitch can be called wherever you want, nothing more. In php in general you have several ways to keep data : DB, session, cookie, .... But a service is not made to keep data ! It's just a simple php function callable everywhere by every controller. But you can save data in this service using session and get them threw this service too. Basically set*** -> set parameter in the session get*** -> get parameter from this session. Hope i'm clear and this will help you